# can I able to dynamically intercept the endpoints in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I need to dynamically intercept endpoint based on some tenant configuration.is there any way to dynamically intercept endpoint while starting the camel context

Answer (score 0):

[camel intercept](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html) lets you do this...

```
intercept().when(body().contains("Hello")).to("mock:intercepted");

from("direct:start")
    .to("mock:foo", "mock:bar", "mock:result");
```